# Sheaf on a filtered topological space?

Tags: gn.general-topology, sheaf-theory

Is there any nice way of defining a sheaf of abelian groups on a filtered topological space?

Let $X$ equipped with filtration $X_0\subset X_1\subset X_2\subset ... \subset X_k=X$ be an object in the category $Filt(Top)$ of filtered topological spaces. How could one define a sheaf $X\rightarrow Ab$ on $X$ that respects the filtration?

I was thinking about sheaves that are constructible with respect to such a filtration, but am curious about other ideas.

EDIT: Some more info - The ways that come to mind always involve considering a family of sheaves $F_i$ with $F_j$ defined on $X_j$ but is there a way to combine this information into one sheaf?

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you want and what you need to do with it. Can you be a little more informative, please?

Comment: It's still not clear what it is you're asking. Are you asking "what is a constructible sheaf"? Or "can I revover a constructible sheaf from its value on strata?" (No.) Or "what information do I need in addition to its values on strata?" (You need the gluing data. For example, if there's only one proper closed stratum, then you need (1) a locally constant sheaf on the closed guy, (2) a locally constant sheaf on the open guy, and (3) a map from the sheaf on the closed guy to the `germ of the open part on the closed part', i.e. what you get by pushing forward then restricting to the closed bit.)

Answer (score 1):

The most natural way seems to be to take a sheaf on $X$ and to restrict it to the levels of the filtration, so you get a directed system of sheafs. To build the restriction of the sheaf to $X_k$ from the inclusion map of $X_k$ to $X$, you probably want to use inverse image functors.  It also sounds like you are looking to something more flexible than that but I don't know either if it can be done.

Comment: So your answer to the question "How could one define a sheaf that respects the filtration?" is "any sheaf"?